# Ocassional error 400 when sending requests in golang

Tags: http, go, python-requests, discord

Here's what I have right now:

```
func (client Client) PressButton(i int, k int, msg Message) error {
    if client.Token == "" {
        return fmt.Errorf("no token")
    }
    i--
    k--

    url := "https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions"
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    data := map[string]interface{}{"component_type": msg.Components[i].Buttons[k].Type, "custom_id": msg.Components[i].Buttons[k].CustomID, "hash": msg.Components[i].Buttons[k].Hash}
    values := map[string]interface{}{"application_id": "270904126974590976", "channel_id": msg.ChannelID, "type": "3", "data": data, "guild_id": msg.GuildID, "message_flags": 0, "message_id": msg.ID,}
    json_data, err := json.Marshal(values)

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error while encoding button click as json: %v", err)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, strings.NewReader(string(json_data)))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error while creating http request: %v", err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("authorization", client.Token)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    httpClient := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error while sending http request: %v", err)
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 204 {
        switch resp.StatusCode {
        case http.StatusUnauthorized:
            return ErrUnauthorized
        case http.StatusForbidden:
            return ErrForbidden
        case http.StatusNotFound:
            return ErrNotFound
        case http.StatusTooManyRequests:
            return ErrTooManyRequests
        case http.StatusInternalServerError:
            return ErrIntervalServer
        default:
            return fmt.Errorf("unexpected status code while clicking button: %v", resp.StatusCode)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This works perfectly 90% of the times. But sometimes I get an error 400. I looked it up, I tried every recommended solution, I have confirmed that the payload and the URL are absolutely right moreover it wouldn't work most of the times if they weren't. I've also tried changing the headers among other things.

Here's an example payload that was sent (Before Marshaling) :

```
map[application_id:12345 channel_id:872747211551801384 data:map[component_type:2 custom_id:c34117ee-a332-4d7c-888f-47081e40092f:0 hash:]
```

(Changed the application id)

Response status is 400, here's the response body:

```
{"code": 50035, "errors": {"data": {"_errors": [{"code": "COMPONENT_VALIDATION_FAILED", "message": "Component validation failed"}]}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}
```

I've absolutely scavanged the internet and coding servers on discord to understand why this is happening.
The hash is always an empty field now, earlier it used to have a value for my use-case. I just left it in so it's more generalized.

Comment: Golang's `map` type has no sorting rule for its elements, so when the marshaller ranges over it the order can be anything even for maps which are deep-equal. If the API is sensitive to key-order (it **shouldn't** be, but I didn't write it) this can cause random failures. Try creating your own `type RequestData struct {}` where you can control the key order.

Comment: Hey! thank you for responding, just tried this ^ still getting many 400's

Comment: You should definitely try logging the contents of `string(json_data)` before `httpClient.Do()` in some way. Make sure you can match the contents to any errors in the output. If there is still trouble you should try finding a Discord Server about Discord API; there should be many people willing to help.

Comment: I double checked everything once again. The request seems fine to me. I joint a couple discord API servers, people are apprehensive of answering as "userbots are against discord TOS" but that doesn't answer my question haha

Comment: Hey, do you mind sharing how you got the response body? I'm getting a 400 error but I cannot get the error body to see what caused it.